# Connecting Kotlin-Variable with Activity-XML

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm beginning to develop a Application for Android. Before, I've some years experience with C++/Python an QT/PySide (everything handwritten), so, it's very confusing for me, to handle the GUI in a xml and the Actions in the kt-file. 
Now I'm using Kotlin in the Android Studio. After I follow a outdated tutorial, I try to get a very simple "Browser" with textedit (for the url), a "Go"-Button and the webview to show the site.

After getting the Webview (with help of the Tutorial) working in the way I want it, I stumbled now about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Go" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
}
}
```

At TextView and Button I got the error:
"Function invocation 'TextView(...)' expected" (or, instead of TextView: Button).
What I've to do, to get the Views connect to my function?

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following part of code is not Kotlin, but Java.

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
```

Here is equivalent code, written in Kotlin

```
    val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
```

Click [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) to read more about basic Kotlin syntax. And [here](https://www.kotlinvsjava.com/) you can find nice comparisons between Java and Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin we don't need to do findViewById() stuff you can directly access xml view in kt
file.
Lets take your xml example.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/yourEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yourButton"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Go" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You have two ids in xml youEditText and yourButton. Below is the way to access in kotlin
file.

```
 youEditText.text="Set whatever value you want to set"

 youButton.text="Click on button text"
```

Hope it help you.Happy Coding.

Comment: Using Kotlin's synthetic, DataBinding and ViewBinding should be used only when someone understand basics.